# why is program crashing after assign string

Tags: string, delphi, crash

I have class with integers and string and  when i use integers everything is fine but when i use string program is crashing

```
//class
CatInfoType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FcatId: Integer;
    FcatName: string;
    FcatParent: Integer;
    FcatPosition: Integer;
    FcatIsProductCatalogueEnabled: Integer;
  published
    property catId : Integer read FcatId write FcatId;
    property catName : string read FcatName write FcatName;
    property catParent : Integer read FcatParent write FcatParent;
    property catPosition : Integer read FcatPosition write FcatPosition;
    property catIsProductCatalogueEnabled: Integer 
                                       read FcatIsProductCatalogueEnabled 
                                       write FcatIsProductCatalogueEnabled;
end;
//program code 
procedure TForm2.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rc: Integer;
  k: CatInfoType;
  l:String;
begin
  k.catId:=4646;
  k.catName:='777';//that crashing the program
end;
```

Comment: "is crashing" and "crashes the program" is not a problem description. What **specifically** does "crashes" mean? (It's clear you're getting an access violation, but that information should be included in your question, along with the exact error message you get. In fact, searching for that error message in Google would have found you an answer without even needing to ask here. https://www.google.com/search?q=Access+Violation+at+address+xxxxxxxx+in+module+Read+of+address+0x00000000)

Answer (score 8):

No...not quite

```
k.catId:=4646; //  <--- that crashing the program
k.catName:='777';
```

The error message you could have included would have been something like

> Access Violation at address xxxxxxxx in module 'MyProject.exe'. Read of address xxxxxxxx.

Here `k` is a class of `CatInfoType` - you haven't yet instantiated it, however.  What you want is :

```
k := CatInfoType.Create;
k.catId := 4646;
//... etc
```

Comment: The assignment of the integer might succeed, although it would likely corrupt memory. The string assignment is less likely to succeed because the current value will be finalised. That is the likely point of failure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Possible, I suppose.  I'm guessing OP found the instruction pointer had incremented to the second line after breaking, however, and figured that was the cause of the problem.  Either way...

Comment: It doesn't bear analysis. No object created, no dice. Nothing more needs to be said. Create the object and move on! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You failed to instantiate an instance. That would be done with

```
k := CatInfoType.Create(...);
```